# Deserialize two properties into one .NET property

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

I have a json response like this

```
{ latitude: 30.4848, longitude: -70.5484 }
```

Now I'm doing this to deserialize with newtonsoft JSON.NET

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);
```

and deserializing into this

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "longitude")]
    public double Longitude{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "latitude")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

I want to deserialize the latitude and longitude as Longitude and Latitude propeties of a GeoCoordinate object

```
public class Test
{
    public GeoCoordinate Location{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I like @qntmfred suggestion +1.  This question leads me to believe you're adding unnecessary complexity to a simple app

Comment: You are right I didn't understand the suggestion until @qntmfred expanded it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not quite what you asked, but you could define `Location` like this instead

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Test
{
    private GeoCoordindate _location;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "longitude")]
    public double Longitude{ get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "latitude")]
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public GeoCoordinate Location
    {
        get
        {
            if (_location == null)
                _location = new GeoCoordinate(Latitude, Longitude);

            return _location;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added a few line trying to explain myself better